# AIR for iOS Info.plist adjustments?

Tags: ios, iphone, air, adobe

So we're trying to release our app on iOS, but an old version supported devices AIR no longer supports and we're getting an error.

I've spoken to Apple and the fix for this is to limit our app to iOS 7 or above, which we've done with InfoAdditions. We still get the error because our AIR app still includes armv7 and opengles 2.0 as requirements in the Info.plist file.

Is there a way we can remove these UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities from the info.plist file? The app will still be limited to devices that support it due to the iOS 7 requirement we have added. From where I'm standing, it looks like we'd have to build the .ipa with AIR, edit the Info.plist and then re-package, but this has us completely lost.